How to automate transferring customers from one realm to another in SFCC BM
We have two websites A and B and we have a customer profile custom attribute portalId. Now we have customers on website A with portalId as B, we need these customers to have their profile on realm B on the salesforce commerce cloud business manager and remove it from A. Is there a way to automate this process as there are lots of customers like these?
